# Cannot see datasources in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I was trying to install Apache Superset on Windows. Datasources are not loading. I don't understand how to change this.

I've followed [these installation instructions](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose) and received this output:

```
| Init Step 3/4 [Starting] -- Setting up roles and perms
superset_init         |
superset_init         |
superset_init         | ######################################################################
superset_init         |
superset_init         | 'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
superset_init         | logging was configured successfully
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:16,770:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:16,777:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
superset_init         | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_limiter/extension.py:293: UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
superset_init         |   warnings.warn(
superset_init         | 'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
superset_init         | Syncing role definition
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:19,419:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing role definition
superset_init         | Syncing Admin perms
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:19,434:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Admin perms
superset_init         | Syncing Alpha perms
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:19,583:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Alpha perms
superset_init         | Syncing Gamma perms
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:19,735:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing Gamma perms
superset_init         | Syncing sql_lab perms
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:19,895:INFO:superset.security.manager:Syncing sql_lab perms
superset_init         | Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:20,039:INFO:superset.security.manager:Fetching a set of all perms to lookup which ones are missing
superset_init         | Creating missing datasource permissions.
superset_init         | 2023-08-24 14:00:20,178:INFO:superset.security.manager:Creating missing datasource permissions.
superset_init         | Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py]
superset_init         | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.py", line 126, in decrypt
superset_init         |     decrypted = decrypted.decode('utf-8')
superset_init         | UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 5: invalid start byte
superset_init         |
superset_init         | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
superset_init         |
superset_init         | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 33, in <module>
superset_init         |     sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
superset_init         |     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
superset_init         |     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
superset_init         |     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
superset_init         |     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
superset_init         |     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
superset_init         |     return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 357, in decorator
superset_init         |     return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
superset_init         |     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
superset_init         |     return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 357, in decorator
superset_init         |     return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
superset_init         |     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
superset_init         |   File "/app/superset/cli/main.py", line 65, in init
superset_init         |     security_manager.sync_role_definitions()
superset_init         |   File "/app/superset/security/manager.py", line 801, in sync_role_definitions
superset_init         |     self.create_missing_perms()
superset_init         |   File "/app/superset/security/manager.py", line 751, in create_missing_perms
superset_init         |     merge_pv("datasource_access", datasource.get_perm())
superset_init         |   File "/app/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py", line 671, in get_perm
superset_init         |     if self.database is None:
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 481, in __get__
superset_init         |     return self.impl.get(state, dict_)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 941, in get
superset_init         |     value = self._fire_loader_callables(state, key, passive)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 977, in _fire_loader_callables
superset_init         |     return self.callable_(state, passive)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 911, in _load_for_state
superset_init         |     return self._emit_lazyload(
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 997, in _emit_lazyload
superset_init         |     return loading.load_on_pk_identity(
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 541, in load_on_pk_identity
superset_init         |     return result.one()
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1417, in one
superset_init         |     return self._only_one_row(
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 559, in _only_one_row
superset_init         |     row = onerow(hard_close=True)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1281, in _fetchone_impl
superset_init         |     return self._real_result._fetchone_impl(hard_close=hard_close)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1684, in _fetchone_impl
superset_init         |     row = next(self.iterator, _NO_ROW)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 147, in chunks
superset_init         |     fetch = cursor._raw_all_rows()
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 393, in _raw_all_rows
superset_init         |     return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 393, in <listcomp>
superset_init         |     return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 1681, in process
superset_init         |     return process_value(impl_processor(value), dialect)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.py", line 479, in process_result_value
superset_init         |     value = super().process_result_value(value=value, dialect=dialect)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.py", line 424, in process_result_value
superset_init         |     decrypted_value = self.engine.decrypt(value)
superset_init         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.py", line 128, in decrypt
superset_init         |     raise ValueError('Invalid decryption key')
superset_init         | ValueError: Invalid decryption key
superset_init exited with code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher thanks! I solved this question, that was the problem with the doker. It remembered the old configurations and deleting volumes helped.